# Reset List When Condition Met

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to make a function that reads through a protocol buffer and creates a dictionary with a list matched up to each key, like so:

```
Source:
  {
    name: "foo"
    ...
    some_value: "a"
    some_value: "b"
  },
  {
    name: "bar"
    ...
    some_value: "c"
    some_value: "d"
  }

Desired Output:
  {'foo': ['a','b'], 'bar': ['c','d',]}
```

Here is my code:

```
import re

STATIC_SRC = '/path/to/my/file.txt'

def CountBrackets(line):
  if '{' in line:
    return 1
  if '}' in line:
    return -1
  else:
    return 0

with open(STATIC_SRC, 'r') as src_file:
  bracket_count = 0
  key = ''
  values = []
  my_dict = {}

  for line in src_file:
    line = line.strip()
    bracket_count += CountBrackets(line)

    # Finds line like 'name: "foo"' and stores 'foo' as key
    if line.startswith('name:'):
      key = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)
      key = ''.join(key)

    # Finds line like 'some_value: "a"' and adds 'a' to list
    if line.startswith('some_value:'):
      value = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)
      values.append(value)

    # When bracket count returns to 0, it's reached the end of a tupe
    # and should store the current key and list.
    if bracket_count == 0:
      my_dict[key] = values
      del values[:] # This is where I'm having issues.

  print(role_dict)
```

My problem is that I can't get the list to successfully clear at the end of the tuple (in the source file). I have tried the following two methods, neither gave the correct output.

```
Method:
  values = []
Result:
  {'foo': ['a', 'b'], 'bar': ['a','b','c','d']}

Method:
  del values[:]
Result:
  {'foo': [], 'bar': []}
```

I've had it print all the keys/values as it loops and those are working as desired. It's also writing to the dictionary at the write time based on bracket count. It seems that the method I used for clearing somehow clears 'values' even after they've been added to the dictionary.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going wrong here and how to properly empty the list of values? Thanks!

EDIT: By request, tl;dr

I'd like the program to loop through this logic:

```
if x:
  - store something to 'key'
if y:
  - add something to a list 'values'
if z:
  - write the current 'key' and 'values' to a dictionary
  - clear the list 'values'
```

How do I clear the list of values at the end?

Comment: "My problem is that I can't get the list to successfully clear at the end of the tuple." What tuple? How about  a minimum example of the desired behaviour instead of your whole code?

Comment: Please write code that I can enter into an interpreter.

Comment: Added a 'minimum example' to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting that output on your first attempt. It worked for me. See below.

```py
with open(STATIC_SRC, 'r') as src_file:
  bracket_count = 0
  key = ''
  values = []
  my_dict = {}

  for line in src_file:
    print(values)
    line = line.strip()
    bracket_count += CountBrackets(line)

    # Finds line like 'name: "foo"' and stores 'foo' as key
    if line.startswith('name:'):
      key = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)
      key = ''.join(key)

    # Finds line like 'some_value: "a"' and adds 'a' to list
    if line.startswith('some_value:'):
      value = re.findall('"([^"]*)"', line)
      values.extend(value)  # append create a new list inside the existing list

    # When bracket count returns to 0, it's reached the end of a tupe
    # and should store the current key and list.
    if bracket_count == 0:
      my_dict[key] = values
      values = []

  print(my_dict)  # the name of the dict was wrong
```

The result is

```py
{'foo': ['a', 'b'], 'bar': ['c', 'd']}
```

I just edited the last print and replaced append with extend.

You cannot `del values` because that will delete the value in the dict, as it is the same object in memory.

```py
d = {}
k = [1,2,3]
d['a'] = k
d
#  {'a': [1, 2, 3]}
id(d['a']) == id(k)
#  True
```

Running Python 2.7.6.

Comment: I went back to this method and it worked for me as well! l guess I must have had a typo in there. Thanks for still explaining the issue with using delete in this instance.